# Communication between WCF server and client via LAN failed

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wcf

I am trying communicate between client and server, that are created with Microsoft WCF - netTcpBinding in C# and server runs as Windows Service. Server runs on my virtual LAN as single PC. But communication always failed with error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The server has rejected the client credentials.
```

On localhost all works correctly. Client downloads ServiceReference from this IP address too.

Server app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WCFHostService.MyServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WCFHostService.MyServiceBehavior" name="WCFServiceHost.MyService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
              name="NetTcpBindingEndpoint" contract="WCFServiceHost.IMyService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
            name="MexTcpBindingEndpoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://10.0.0.1:8523/WCFTestService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name = "netTcpBinding">
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Client App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="NetTcpBindingEndpoint" />
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://10.0.0.1:8523/WCFTestService" binding="netTcpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBindingEndpoint" contract="ServiceReference1.IMyService"
                name="NetTcpBindingEndpoint">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="&#xD;&#xA;          " />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I think that probably problem will be in security settings in config file. What is wrong there please? Becasue in TCPView on server system I see Remote address of MyService only "his local computer name", not * (all). Thanks for your replies.